# Non reduced projective schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be separated noetherian scheme. Suppose that $X_{red}$ (the associated reduced scheme) is projective. Does it follow that $X$ is also projective ? Otherwise what are the minimal conditions on $X$ ?

Comment: Note that being "projective" is a property of a *morphism of schemes*.  Is the base scheme the spectrum of a field? Or is the base scheme   Spec $\mathbb{Z}$? Or is it an arbitrary scheme $S$?

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar I need this for schemes over the field of complex numbers, but maybe it is also interesting in a more general context

Comment: This is not true. If $Y$ is a (projective) variety over a field with $H^2(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y) \neq 0$ then quite often there will be deformations $Y'$ of $Y$ over $Spec(k[\epsilon])$ so that no ample bundle on $Y$ lifts to $Y'$ so $Y'$ will not be projective (as a scheme over $k$). For an actual exaxmple, you can take $Y$ to be an abelian variety of dimension $> 1$.